# How to display image which is receiving from PHP via ajax?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have to display the image which is receiving from PHP via ajax. I am able to display the name `<span id="pic_name">Pic name here</span>` but how can I display the image like `<img src="images/pic/picname" />`

```
   //alert(a);
         $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                   url: "includes/compare.php", // 
                   data:'id='+a,
                 success: function(msg){
                 msg = msg.split(',');
                 $("#pics_name").html("<img src='images/profile/"+msg+"' alt='' />");
                 $("#pics_user").html(msg);
                 $("#username").html(msg);
                 $("#email").html(msg);
                      },
                    error: function(){
                    alert("failure");
                    }
                  });
```

**PHP**

```
 $compare_u=$_POST['id'];
                $sql_compare="SELECT * FROM request WHERE Id=$compare_u";
                $compare_query=$conn->query($sql_compare);
                if ($compare_query->num_rows > 0) {
                while($userdata12=$compare_query->fetch_assoc()){ 
                    $compare_pic=$userdata12['profile_pic'];
                    $compare_name=$userdata12['Name'];
                   $compare_user=$userdata12['username'];
                   $compare_user=$userdata12['email'];
                }
            }
         exit();
```

And How can we display the multiple values?

Comment: Where's your PHP?

Comment: Are you receiving the image, or just a path reference to the image?  What are "the multiple values"?  What's *actually in* your `msg` variable and what isn't working?

Comment: when your ajax success at that time in `msg` you get image name?

Comment: Yes @JaykumarGondaliya I am getting the image name.

Comment: @JonStirling I don't think so you require my PHP code I am not able to display the image using AJAX. I am getting the image name

Comment: Then don't tag and name PHP...

Answer (score 0):

Check updated code below..

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "includes/compare.php", // 
  data:'id='+a,
  success: function(msg){
    myObj = JSON.parse(msg);
    for (x in myObj) {
      $("#pics_name").html("<img src='images/profile/"+myObj[x].profile_pic+"' alt='' />"); 
      $("#pics_user").html(myObj[x].Name); 
      $("#username").html(myObj[x].username);
      $("#email").html(myObj[x].email);
    }
  },
  error: function(){
    alert("failure");
  }
});
```

```html
<?php 
  $compare_u=$_POST['id'];
 $sql_compare="SELECT * FROM request WHERE Id=$compare_u";
 $compare_query=$conn->query($sql_compare);
 if ($compare_query->num_rows > 0) {
  $outp = array();
  $outp = $compare_query->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  echo json_encode($outp);
 }
 exit();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr, Super User, How do I set my path. I did like this  $("#pics_peer").html("<img src='/images/profile/"+msg+"' alt='' />");

Comment: Mr.Super User, How can we display the multiple data? I mean I am also getting the name, image, email id etc.

Comment: in which format you get the multiple data, `json/array` or other?

Comment: I just want to display the name and image which is coming from the database with the help of PHP via AJAX. Image is displaying with the help of your code but not able to display the image name

Comment: If your result come in array format ('imageName','imagePath') then you can split it and use it like below ..
`msg = msg.split(','); 
$("#pics_name").html('<img src="/images/profile/'+msg[1]+'" alt="'+msg[0]+'" />');`

Comment: $("#pics_name").html("<img src='images/profile/"+msg+"' alt='' />");
$("#pics_user").html(msg);//user
 $("#username").html(msg);//username
$("#email").html(msg);//email

Comment: How do I display the records each one by one.That's my question

Comment: can you share what data comes after ajax success, so i can write full code for this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152706/discussion-between-narendra-verma-and-super-user).

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "includes/compare.php", // 
  data:'id='+a,
  success: function(msg){
  //here  As Image Tag that you create
  // ==> $("#pics_name").html("<img src='"+m-sg+"' alt='' />"); 

 //here  we set directly SRC in Image
  $("#my_image_tag").attr("src",msg);


  },
  error: function(){
    alert("failure");
  }
});
```

Comment: bro are you sure you got the image name in `msg`?

Comment: and you can try also `dataType: "json"` and please share Your compare.php code that returns this ajax